# Automatically triaging and/or resolving Jira tickets using expert systems?

Tags: automation, jira, expert-system

Has anyone looked into auto-triage'ing and/or auto-resolving Jira tickets, using expert systems such as LogicNets?

Goal is not to completely automate all tickets, just reduce workload needed to auto-resolve simple tickets, and enable support engineers to focus on more complicated issues.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is using REST API, check https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

If you tool can do some sort of GET or POST with a trigger, or could be programmatic extended then you could do almost everything in Jira, you can even use shell scripts with curl to make the rest calls in linux/mac terminal.